# ruby/rails - Converting Entire Database Field (from string to date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have made a huge mistake.

Initially I created my model with a field called start_date and made it a string to keep track of event dates.

Now I'm realizing it would be nice to have this field as a date type so I could do calculations like find events where start_date is between today and 1 month from now.

This issue is I already have 500 records so starting over would suck....

The format of the start_date field is in a rails compatible type " 2011-02-21 22:00:00 " but its just a string...

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try just doing an **EXPORT** on the table (making sure to only export data, do not include CREATE and/or DROP table commands).

Create a **migration** to change the datatype

**TRUNCATE** the table

**IMPORT** the data

Since the column is now a date field, it should parse the input of a string just fine, considering that's what you provide it anyway

Answer (score 4):

1. Create a migration to add a `start_date_2` column of the type you want
2. `Model.find(:all).each { |i| i.update_attributes(:start_date_2, Date.new(i.start_date)) }`
3. Create a migration to delete `start_date` and to rename `start_date_2` to `start_date`

This should work, out of the top of my head.

Comment: Let me know, I'm curious now.

Comment: I migrated and just changed the data type, I guess since the strings were in a datetime  compatible format I didn't do any formal conversions

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you can do away with the risk of changing column type if there is live data. The parse methods can save you. From Ruby-doc:

```
parse(str='-4712-01-01', comp=true, sg=ITALY) 
Create a new Date object by parsing from a String, without specifying the format.

str is a String holding a date representation. comp specifies whether to interpret 2-digit years as 19XX (>= 69) or 20XX (< 69); the default is not to. The method will attempt to parse a date from the String using various heuristics; see _parse in date/format.rb for more details. If parsing fails, an ArgumentError will be raised.
```

[Here](http://whynotwiki.com/Ruby_/_Dates_and_times#How_do_I_turn_a_string_into_a_Date.3F) and [here](http://codeidol.com/other/rubyckbk/Date-and-Time/Parsing-Dates,-Precisely-or-Fuzzily/) are some more examples / explanations. Hope this helps.